# Replace all quote marks but leave escaped characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove all quote characters from a string but not those that are escaped.

Example:

> `#TEST string "quoted part\" which escapes" other "quoted string"`

Should result in:

> `#TEST string quoted part\" which escapes other quoted string`

I tried to achieve this using

```
$string = '#TEST string "quoted part\" which escapes" other "quoted string"'
preg_replace("/(?>=\\)([\"])/","", $string);
```

But can't seem to find a match pattern.

Any help or tip on an other approach

Comment: You may try `preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)\"/","", $string);`... Well, if you can have escaped backslashes it won't work, you will need `preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\{2})*)\"/","$1", $string);`

Comment: How should i write it to get desired result then?

Comment: Can backslashes be escaped?

Comment: `preg_replace("/([^\\\\])[\"']/", "$1", $string);` but it wouldn't remove `quotes after escaped \\"back slash"`

Comment: The dirty solution would be to first replace `\"` by some unique string, which is guaranteed not to be in you string, then replace all `"` and afterwards place back the `\"`

Comment: Your regex is incomplete. If it starts with `/` it must end with another `/`. Also, enclose the regex in apostrophes (`'`). This way you don't have to escape the quotes (`"`) and, if they are not followed by an apostrophe, you don't have to escape (double) the backslashes (`\ `) either (to match the PHP encoding of strings). You still have to escape them to follow the regex semantic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very good example for `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`:

```
\\['"](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|["']
```

Replace this with an empty string and you're fine. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/OqNC1F/1/).

---

In `PHP` this would be (you need to escape the backslash as well):

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
#TEST string "quoted part\" witch escape" other "quoted string"
DATA;

$regex = '~\\\\[\'"](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|["\']~';

$string = preg_replace($regex, '', $string);
echo $string;

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/CjrmeE).

Comment: This did indeed solve the problem! I need to read on about that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This won't work if escaped backslashes may appear in the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your input. But in this particular case that won't be a problem :)

Comment: @PhilipG: That means you may use `preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)[\"']/","", $string);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes you are correct. I tried a bunch of different regex's but I missed the part about "double escaping", probably thats why I didn't get it to work!

Answer (score 2):

While `(*SKIP)(*F)` is a good technique all in all, it seems you may use a mere negative lookbehind in this case, *where no other escape entities may appear but escaped quotes*:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)[\"']/","", $string);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6DHwyH/1).

Here, the regex matches...

- `(?<!\\\\)` - a position inside the string that is not immediately preceded with a literal backslash (note that in PHP string literals, you need two backslashes to define a literal backslash, and to match a literal backslash with a regex pattern, the literal backslash in the string literal must be doubled since the backslash is a special regex metacharacter)
- `[\"']` - a double or single quote.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/KeOZk2):

```
$str = '#TEST string "quoted part\\" witch escape" other "quoted string"';
$res = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)[\'"]/', '', $str);
echo $res;
// => #TEST string quoted part\" witch escape other quoted string
```

**In case backslashes may also be escaped in the input**, you need to make sure you do not match a `"` that comes after two `\\` (since in that case, a `"` is not escaped):

```
preg_replace("/(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\{2})*)[\"']/",'$1', $string);
```

The `((?:\\\\{2})*)` part will capture paired `\`s before `"` or `'` and will put them back with the help of the `$1` backreference.

Answer (score 1):

May be this

```
$str = '#TEST string "quoted part\" witch escape" other "quoted string"';

echo preg_replace("#([^\\\])\"#", "$1", $str);
```